# Change variable value with regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a string: `http://user_name:user_password@example.com/gitproject.git`
and want to make it without user and pass - `http://example.com/gitproject.git`

i.e.

```
http://user_name:user_password@example.com/gitproject.git
```

to

```
http://example.com/gitproject.git
```

How can I do it automatically in bash?

Answer (score 2):

Some languages you may have installed such as php or python have excellent URL parsing facilities.  For example, php:

```
$url = parse_url("http://user_name:user_password@example.com/gitproject.git "); 
return "$url[scheme]://" . $url['host'] . $url['path'];
```

However, since that's not what you asked for, you can still do it in `sed`:

```
sed -r "s#(.*?://).*?@(.*)#\1\2#" <<<"http://user:pass@example.com/git"
```

Answer (score 2):

This **`sed`** should work:

```
s="http://user_name:user_password@example.com/gitproject.git"
sed 's~^\(.*//\)[^@]*@\(.*\)$~\1\2~' <<< "$s"

http://example.com/gitproject.git
```

**Using pure BASH**

```
echo "${s/*@/http://}"

http://example.com/gitproject.git
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed "s#//.*@#//#g" <<< "http://user_name:user_password@example.com/gitproject.git"
http://example.com/gitproject.git
```

Comment: The output is not what the OP asked for though

Answer (score 1):

A pure bash possibility

```
var='http://user_name:user_password@example.com/gitproject.git'
pat='(http://).*?@(.*)'
[[ $var =~ $pat ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
http://example.com/gitproject.git
```